# Can boot only via Recovery Mode

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia

The problem is that I can boot only via Recovery Mode.

- If I try to boot normally, the purple blank screen appears and nothing happens
- If I try to boot with another Kernel, the same exact thing happens but with 2 lines saying something I don't remember (Not something serious but I can post about it later)
- If I try to "**dpkg**" via recovery mode still same thing
- I tried "**update-grub**" also.
- If I try to install Nvidia driver, it just won't for some reason.
- **All started when I installed the Macbuntu theme.**
  http://www.noobslab.com/2016/04/macbuntu-1604-transformation-pack-for.html
  No I didn't install anything that has to do with booting screen or anything like that. Just the fonts, Mac icons etc. and the plank.
- Also, after I installed Mac theme I couldn't restart instantly. When I tried to restart via GUI, it just logged out and got me back to Ubuntu login screen **but without the mac theme**.

  `sudo lshw -c video`

  ```
     *-display UNCLAIMED      
          description: VGA compatible controller
          product: GK107 [GeForce GTX 650]
          vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
          physical id: 0 
          bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
          version: a1
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 33MHz 
          capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
          configuration: latency=0
          resources: memory:fd000000-fdffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff
          ioport:e000(size=128) memory:fe000000-fe07ffff
  ```

Comment: try adding `vga=788` to the kernel boot args, press `e` during grub boot